# JQuery Slider change track style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have been successful in customizing my slider to my needs, but I am not able to change the width of the track.

[Documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/) tells my to use `ui-slider` or `ui-slider-vertical` but this does not seam to work.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/delcon/49p4grkn/2/) is my fiddle.

I would like to change the width of the track an maybe add rounded corners to achieve a lighter appearance.

Comment: Post some code instead of "Here is my fiddle"

Comment: just set the width in the #slider css class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
#slider {
  /* ... */
  width: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
#slider .ui-slider-range-min {
  /* ... */
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/46emm82n/)